# How to create custom window user control in WPF?

Tags: wpf, user-controls, custom-controls

How to create custom window using user control or is there any way to do this?, i want to create one custom window and that 'll be common for all windows.

Thanks,
@nagaraju.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Create your base class say BaseClassView and inherit from Window class and then inherit your "Wpf window as

```
<view:BaseClassView x:Class="MyProject.Views.AddressView" <!- here AddressView inhetrits the BaseClassView -->
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:view="clr-namespace:namespace of BaseClassView ">

</view:BaseClassView>

public partial class AddressView /*Do not inherit this class with Window rather inherit BaseClassView (base class with Window class)*/
{

}
```

hope this will help

Comment: xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:view="clr-namespace:namespace of BaseClassView " >

Comment: <view:BaseView x:Class="MyProject.Views.MaintainAddressView" 







xmlns="schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"; xmlns:x="schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"; xmlns:view="clr-namespace:namespace of BaseClassView " 
>   </view: